# Are there any ways to make diminutive forms of nouns in Korean?

Tags: word-usage

Many languages have a way to create diminutive forms, which can denote small size, or be a term of endearment.

One English example is "-y" : dog becomes doggy, Bob can become Bobby, and so on.

In Italian, "-ino" and "-ina" can be used; A girl called Chiara might be called 'Chiarina'. "Topo" is a mouse, so "topolino" is a "little mouse".

The [List of diminutives by language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diminutives_by_language) on Wikipedia doesn't currently mention any ways to make diminutives in Korean. Is there anything at all similar in Korean? (Not necessarily a suffix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diminutives are called 지소사 in Korean. There are several:

> - **-아지** : most common one.
>
>   - 모가지(목 + -아지): neck
>   - 소가지(속 + -아지): mind (noun)
>   - 망아지(말 + -아지): foal
>   - 송아지(소 + -아지): calf
>   - 강아지(개 + -아지): puppy
> - **-앙이**
>
>   - 고양이 (괴 + -앙이): cat, kitten
>   - 꼬랑이 (꼬리 + -앙이): tail
>   - 가장이 (가지 + -앙이): branch
>   - 나방이 (나비 + -앙이): moth
> - **좀-** : usually used in plant names
>
>   - 파리 - 좀파리
>   - 가지풀 - 좀가지풀
>   - 딸기 - 좀딸기
>   - 민들레 - 좀민들레
>   - 목이버섯 - 좀목이버섯
> - **졸-** : usually used in plant names
>
>   - 참나무 - 졸참나무
>   - 갈매나무 - 졸갈매나무
> - **애기-** : usually used in plant names
>
>   - 똥풀 - 애기똥풀
>   - 장대 - 애기장대
>   - 땅빈대 - 애기땅빈대

Other diminutive prefixes used in plant names include '난쟁이-', '어리-', etc.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: -아지/-앙이 are not productive and can be only used for a handful of already established forms.  (E.g., you can't add -아지 to 쥐 and create 쥐아지.)  The others are more like specialized biological terms, used for some species' names.